# getParent.add(component)

Tags: swing, jtable, jframe, jinternalframe

I am trying to fetch particular value of record from database I used AbstractTableModel to create run time JTable in swings but I am trying to fire query from different javaclass from that class .I provide condition for where clause but I am not able to display that record in other JFrame .AbstractTableModel  is working fine cause I am able to retrive data in same the internalFrame where i am actually declaring the table.. can I retrive that which is in JInternalFrame to JFrame I am trying to use getParent.add() method but it will throw nullpointerException`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at secondproject.select_particular_field$1.actionPerformed(select_particular_field.java:84)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)`

Comment: for better help sonner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: 1) Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) 2) Is your shift key broken so you are no longer able to type I instead of i 3) The same for your enter key, and the dot . Paragraphs make a text easy to read 4) it throws a NullPointerException ... where is your stack trace (and make sure that code is included in the SSCCE) 5) What exactly are you actually asking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit vague, but generally NPE's are thrown because you are invoking a method when the object does not exist. In this case, it appears to happen when you click on a button `select_particular_field.java`

> but I am trying to fire query from different javaclass from that class

Perhaps this is the problem. In the different class, object does not exist/not created yet.

hopefully it helps

Comment: what you said it's right . I am trying to access value without creating object thnxs Nasir